# How can "We consider here how to ... " be rewritten without the personal pronoun "we"?

Tags: personal-pronouns

> We consider here how to solve the problem.

I am trying to rewrite the sentence above without the personal pronoun "we".  My example is as follows:

> It is considered here how to solve the problem.

Does the rewritten sentence make sense? I think "how to solve the problem is considered here" may be better but the subject is too longer.

Comment: A / The solution to the problem is considered here.

Comment: Is  the expression "It is considered how to..."  grammatically incorrect?

Comment: No, but is almost a Yoda sentence.

Comment: How about "a method is considered here how to"?

Comment: *A method ... how to ...* is redundant.  **how** means method or manner or "in what way". If I ask you how you solved the problem, I'm asking for the method you used.

Comment: *Why* do you want to write the sentence without the pronoun "we"?  What is "wrong" with the original sentence?

Comment: For some reasons, I prefer to avoid using personal pronouns as the subject. How about "a consideration will be made about how to..".

Comment: After further search, I found that the following phrase is sometimes used: "It is discussed how to...".  Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: It is grammatically marginal, IMO. If you're going to include a *how*-clause, you can make that clause the subject.  *How to blah blah blah is discussed*. No need to use an *it*-cleft. But if you prefer to write like a non-native speaker, "It is discussed, how to ..." is a perfect choice.

Comment: I don't like the passive voice of any construction such as "it is considered."  There's nobody visibly doing the considering. What's wrong with "we consider?" Or even "I consider?"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are inviting the reader to continue as you discuss solving a problem you have just posed.

To re-write it without using "*we*" you could say:

> How to solve the problem will now be considered.

or

> How to solve the problem will be considered next.

I'm not sure why you are trying to remove "*we*" so this next suggestion may not be suitable, but the above two suggestions are a little formal, so if you want to maintain a conversational manner but simply avoid "we" (for whatever reason), you could also say:

> Let's now consider how to solve the problem.

Comment: "Let's" is "Let us" which is "we".

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree its tantamount to the same, but the OP doesn't say why he is trying to avoid that word. Is it the meaning they are trying to avoid, or just the word? I've given two other good, but entirely impersonal, suggestions. And actually, "we" does not explicitly include the reader. "We" could just refer to multiple authors. "Let us" is more an invitation for the reader to consider the solution *with* the author.